# Avoid generation of build.gradle when using swagger-codegen-plugin

Tags: build.gradle, swagger-codegen

We are using gradle.plugin.org.detoeuf:swagger-codegen-plugin.
**We want to change the content of the build.gradle file in the output directory.**

We added the gradle.build file to the .swagger-codegen-ignore but BOTH .swagger-codegen-ignore file and gradle.build file are re-created every time we call the swagger task.

Our swagger section looks like this

```
swagger {
    inputSpec = "${project.projectDir}/swagger/backoffice-service-api-swagger.json"
    outputDir = file("${project.projectDir}/../backoffice-service-api-client/")
    lang = 'java'
    additionalProperties = [
            'invokerPackage'         : 'com.aaa.bbb.backoffice.service',
            'modelPackage'           : 'com.aaa.bbb.backoffice.service.model',
            'apiPackage'             : 'com.aaa.bbb.backoffice.service.api',
            'dateLibrary'            : 'joda',
            'groupId'                : 'com.aaa.bbb',
            'artifactId'             : 'backoffice-service-api-client',
            'artifactVersion'        : '1.0.0',
            'hideGenerationTimestamp': 'true',
            'dateLibrary'            : 'java8'
    ]
    systemProperties = ["apiTests" : "false"]
}
```

.swagger-codegen-ignore file looks like this -

```
# Swagger Codegen Ignore
# Generated by swagger-codegen https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen

# Use this file to prevent files from being overwritten by the generator.
# The patterns follow closely to .gitignore or .dockerignore.

# As an example, the C# client generator defines ApiClient.cs.
# You can make changes and tell Swagger Codgen to ignore just this file by uncommenting the following line:
#ApiClient.cs

# You can match any string of characters against a directory, file or extension with a single asterisk (*):
#foo/*/qux
# The above matches foo/bar/qux and foo/baz/qux, but not foo/bar/baz/qux

# You can recursively match patterns against a directory, file or extension with a double asterisk (**):
#foo/**/qux
# This matches foo/bar/qux, foo/baz/qux, and foo/bar/baz/qux

# You can also negate patterns with an exclamation (!).
# For example, you can ignore all files in a docs folder with the file extension .md:
#docs/*.md
# Then explicitly reverse the ignore rule for a single file:
#!docs/README.md
build.gradle
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add `ignoreFileOverride` option in additionalProperties as below. The files provided in `ignoreFileOverride` option do not exists in project, then `swagger-codegen` will generate them and if files exist in project then `swagger-codegen` will ignore them.

```
swagger {
    inputSpec = "${project.projectDir}/swagger/backoffice-service-api-swagger.json"
    outputDir = file("${project.projectDir}/../backoffice-service-api-client/")
    lang = 'java'
    additionalProperties = [
            'invokerPackage'         : 'com.aaa.bbb.backoffice.service',
            'modelPackage'           : 'com.aaa.bbb.backoffice.service.model',
            'apiPackage'             : 'com.aaa.bbb.backoffice.service.api',
            'dateLibrary'            : 'joda',
            'groupId'                : 'com.aaa.bbb',
            'artifactId'             : 'backoffice-service-api-client',
            'artifactVersion'        : '1.0.0',
            'hideGenerationTimestamp': 'true',
            'dateLibrary'            : 'java8',
            'ignoreFileOverride'     : '.swagger-codegen-ignore,build.gradle'
    ]
    systemProperties = ["apiTests" : "false"]
}
```

Comment: Files are still overwritten.